# React writing style: lot of repetition when defining component props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am new to react and tried to follow a CRA template based on typescript

When I define a component I use an interface with the props such as

```js
interface CompProps {
A: string
B: number
}
const Comp = ({A, B} : CompProps): JSX.Element => {\\Some code}
```

Here the component have only two props so it seems tidy enough
Yet, I have components with many more props and the phase where I repeat the props name while defining the components bothers me and add many lines of codes.

I am suprised that there is no way to define it in something similar to:

```js
interface CompProps {
A: string
B: number
}
const Comp = (CompProps): JSX.Element => {\\Some code}
```

Am I missing something to allow such a style?

Thanks

Comment: do you mean something like this
`const Comp: React.FC<CompProps> = ({A, B}) => {...your code})`

Comment: How would you access A and B arguments then? CompProps.A? No, that wouldn't work that way.

Comment: You can name your props type anything like:

`interface PooPooF { string_999: string; name: string; }

export const IAMCOMPfjreh123 = ({ name, ...props } : pooPooF) => null;`

or

`type IAMTYPE_INTERFACE_ANYTHING_FOOOPOOOPOOOOOOOKAKA {
children: React.ReactNode;
/* can even be empty */
}

export const JWFJWKFREKF______9999999666 : /*React*/FC<> = (args: IAMTYPE_INTERFACE_ANYTHING_FOOOPOOOPOOOOOOOKAKA) => <>{args.children}</>`

Comment: @duttasuraj Yes, I updated my question to make it more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just not used to React & TS yet. No, there's no such syntax and there's no need for that. You have to duplicate the property names twice because you may want to leave some of those like:

Component.types.ts

```
export interface ComponentProps {
  age?: number;
  name: string;
  surname: string;
}
```

Component.tsx

```
import { FC } from 'react';
import { ComponentProps } from './Component.types';

const Component = ({ age = 18, name, email } : ComponentProps) => {
  return null;
};

/*
or

const Component = ({ email } : ComponentProps) => {
  return null;
};

or

const Component = (props : ComponentProps) => {
  return null;
};

or

const Component : FC<ComponentProps> = (props) => {
  return null;
};

const Component : FC<ComponentProps> = ({ surname }) => {
  return null;
};
*/


export default Component;
```

That's the default TS syntax, same for plain JS + TS functions. You cannot make it shorter. It actually makes more sense to destructure these properties from the arguments object manually, it gives you more control.

I recommend you to learn TS in advance, and then learn React + TS, as things like this will make more sense for you then.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I accepted that answer.
BTW, puting the interface in yet another file is a good practice?

Comment: Also, I will dare to ask. I had a question months ago that did not receive any attention, on a similar topic about practices in react. If by any chance you have a take on that! 73330500/react-pattern-container-logic-component-view-question

Comment: Yes, I actually always do this in production.

It's good for larger apps and makes the files shorter and the code cleaner, also it makes those inetrface reusable, so you can import those in the components that are supposed to be the child components,a nd you can import it in the utils functions.

Ideally you should have all of your types that you use in the app separated in respective .types files. You may have other interfaces/types besides the ones for the props, so all of these should be in .types.ts files.

Comment: OK, I'll have a look and let you know :)

Comment: I think I'll have a chance to answer to your another question tomorrow during the day

Comment: Do not hesitate to just throw me a link with some reading about how to apply the pattern globally at bests, I'd totally accept that as an answer. I couldn't find such a thing while doing my own research

Comment: Yes, sure, I'm busy with my own work today, I've read your questions, will have time to answer during the weekend. It isn't urgent, right?

Comment: No of course, that is already incredibly nice of you to help!

Comment: @zakrapovic, I've strated preparing an answer to your question. Meanwhile, please read this article: https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/dumb-components-and-smart-components-e7b33a698d43

It looks like you have a bunch of component, like every logic piece has a presentational (rendering view) and logical (storing the state and different functions for state manipulations), but accoridng to the Smart and Dumb componnets pattern, you should mostly have the state within the App.tsx (or any other "main" component).